# Route traffic into server across vpn interface (CentOS+OpenPVN)

Tags: routes, centos, devops, openvpn

Using CentOS 7 & OpenVPN I'm wanting to be able to route *to* ip addresses that are connected via openvpn. I have a route setup with GCP where I'm able to ping the tun0 interface 10.8.0.1.

[image]

```
[root@vpn-2 yomateod]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.128.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.128.0.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
10.128.0.11     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
```

I'm having trouble getting 10.8.0.0/24 to route from (external) traffic *into* other connected clients with openvpn.

Any tips/recommendations would be *greatly* appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -I FORWARD -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

:D